# iOS: Sending information to a program that isn't running in foreground or background?

Tags: iphone, background, notifications, communication, launch

I have apps on my phone that pop up notifications in response to events. For example, their are newsreaders that notify me of headlines, or games that notify me when I need to take a turn in networked play.

Seemingly, these apps don't need to have been launched to know to listen for data that could trigger a notification. I get notified that it's my turn to take a turn in a game of Le Havre whether or not I've launched Le Havre since the last time I shut the phone all the way down.

I need a similar feature in an app I'm coding: I need my app to pop a notification in response to a server-sent event, even if the user hasn't launched the app deliberately (so that it can background itself.)

What mechanisms are available to do this?

Answer (score 3):

These are called push notifications because they are "pushed" by a server. The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) is here.

Here's a [tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners/) and [another tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) about them.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Luke's answer, there is one more way to open another application. You can use openURL method in UIApplication with a particular URL Scheme that you have registered.

Please see the tutorial for more detail on how to use : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

For passing data, you can pass in form of arguments.